# Is there a way to change a variable’s value given its name in a function?

Tags: javascript

Is what I’m trying to accomplish possible? I hear using globalThis is the best alternative to window, frames, etc. but I can’t get it to function. Any help would be appreciated!

```
var x = true;
var y = true;

function makeFalse(changeVar) {
  globalThis.changeVar = false;
}

makeFalse("x");
makeFalse("y");

console.log(x); //expecting: false, returning: true
console.log(y); //expecting: false, returning: true
```

Comment: It’s possible (with brackets instead of a dot), but it’s not a good idea. (Even `var` itself is dated, and if you change the `var`s to `let`s, `x` and `y` will stop being properties of the global object.) What are you going to use this ability for?

Comment: Related: ["Variable" variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187530) and [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5117127)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update them using global `window` object or with `this` or with [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) inside the function.

`this` and `globalThis` inside `makeFalse` function refers to global `window` object itself.

```js
var x = true;
var y = true;

function makeFalse(changeVar) {
  // window[changeVar] = false;
  // this[changeVar] = false;
  globalThis[changeVar] = false;
}

makeFalse("x");
makeFalse("y");

console.log(x); //expecting: false, returning: true
console.log(y);
```